# how to change sonarqube admin password

Tags: security, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube 6.4 installed. The default user/password is admin/admin which is working just fine as a local user. For security concern, how can this default password be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the default admin password:

- Log in as that account
- Click on the account icon at the top-right of the screen
- Choose My Account
- Go to the Security tab
- Change password